# Got an error Invalid src prop ('here is a link') on `next/image`, hostname "localhost" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, nextjs-image

I am using the `Image` component from Next.js (it's a new feature of Next.js). I've tried to give the source URL:

```
{`${API}/user/photo/${blog.postedBy.username}`}
```

But it shows me this error. I also make changes in my `next.config.js` as

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
      domains: ['localhost'],
    },
  }
```

but nothing works for me. Please help if you know anything about this.

Comment: What `API`? Is it localhost?

Comment: yeah it is localhost

Comment: In my case, restarting the server solved the problem.

Comment: in a basic form it only needs loader property

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, I finally got the answer. Make loader function to load it from the destination of the image.

```
const myLoader=({src})=>{
  return `${API}/user/photo/${blog.postedBy.username}`;
}
```

Use this loader function the loader attribute of an Image tag.

```
<Image loader={myLoader} src={`${API}/user/photo/${blog.postedBy.username}`} width={500}
    height={500}/>
```

This works for me perfectly

Comment: that works! We can also use the `src` parameter, to make it more flexible: `const myLoader=({src})=>\`${API}${src}\``

Answer (score 50):

```
const src = `${API}/user/photo/${blog.postedBy.username}`;
    
<Image loader={() => src} src={src} width={500} height={500}/>
```

Here, `loader` is a function that generates the URLs for your image. It appends a root domain to your provided src, and generates multiple URLs to request the image at different sizes. These multiple URLs are used in the automatic srcset generation, so that visitors to your site will be served an image that is the right size for their viewport.

Answer (score 29):

Edit **next.config.js** :

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['example.com'],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 22):

There are a whole bunch of out-of-date answers here that suggest setting the `domains` key in `next.config.js`.  As of Next 12.3.0 this is no longer correct; see: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

Instead, one should use a `remotePatterns` property, which is a little more complicated than the old `domains`:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'example.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/account123/**',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: Had to re-run next to remove error. `yarn run dev`

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, You need to restart your dev server, you need to do that each time you make changes on your `next.config.js` file.

The API string should include the port. e.g. `localhost:3001`

Answer (score 4):

Adding `'localhost'` in the domains array will fix the issue,

Unfortunately nextJS didn't refresh the server automatically after configuration file`(next.config.js)` change.

You have to restart the server manually to reflect the changes.

You can also try by set reactStrictMode value  `reactStrictMode: true,`

here is the full export object

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
        domains: [
            "localhost",
            process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL.match(/(http(?:s)?:\/\/)(.*)/)[2], // Valid WP Image domain.
            "2.gravatar.com",
            "0.gravatar.com",
            "secure.gravatar.com",
        ],
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside `next.config.js` file.

Add Image src domain name:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images : {
    domains : ['sangw.in', 'localhost', 'picsum.photos'] // <== Domain name
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, in next.config.js,

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [ "abc.def.org", ]
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

and then in my Image tag

```
<Image
  unoptimized // for image caching, else error
  src={profile.picture}
  alt={profile.picture || "IMG"}
  width={60}
  height={60}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error
Error: Invalid src prop

> (https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/b/m/bmg_0622_11.jpg) on
> `next/image`, hostname "www.example.com" is not configured under
> images in your `next.config.js` See more info:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

Now solve this issue for latest Next.js 13 + version
**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: '**.example.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/media/catalog/product/**',
      },
      
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Now use without any error

```
    <Image
        src={imageurl}
        alt="ecommerce"
        className="object-cover object-center w-full h-full block" 
        width={800}
        height={500}
      />
```

and restart app using **npm run dev** or **yarn dev**

Answer (score 2):

You have to Nothing just add this code in your **next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        domains: ['localhost']
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue, and my domains were correct. Deleting `.next` and `node_modules` folders, and running `yarn/npm install` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For Next.js 13 simply add below to the next.config;

```
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        appDir: true,
    },
    swcMinify: true,
    optimizeFonts: true,
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: "https",
                hostname: "websitename.com",
            },
        ],
        minimumCacheTTL: 15000000,
    },
};
```

This will hopefully solve the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Complete example for localhost.

```
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "HTTP",
        hostname: "localhost",
        port: "3001",
        pathname: "/uploads/**",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all add and restart the dev server.

```
domains: ['localhost']
```

And be sure to return the image link with http(s) protocole

image link with localhost:port/... is wrong , return as http://localhost/... ( or with https )

Answer (score 0):

**Specify the port in next.config.js:**
If your API is running on a different port, you need to include it in the domains array. For example, if your API is running on port 3001, your next.config.js should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost:3000'],
  },
}
```

**Use an absolute URL in your src attribute:**
Instead of relying on the next/image component to automatically resolve the URL, you can provide the absolute URL in your src attribute. For example:

```
  src={`${process.env.API}/user/photo/${blog.postedBy.username}`}
  alt="User Photo"
  width={300}
  height={200}
/>
```

Make sure to restart your Next.js development server after making these changes to see if the issue persists.