# How to upload a photo with React and Next?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm a beginner in React and Next, and I started working on this project. I have a feature where I need to upload a profile picture, but whenever I upload the image this is an error triggered.

Error: Invalid src prop (http://localhost:3333/files/ SOME IMAGE.jpg) on `next/image`, hostname "localhost" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

```
.next\static\chunks\pages\_app.js (604:22) @ defaultLoader

  602 |         }
  603 |         if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test' && !configDomains.includes(parsedSrc.hostname)) {
> 604 |             throw new Error(`Invalid src prop (${src}) on \`next/image\`, hostname "${parsedSrc.hostname}" is not configured under images in your \`next.config.js\`\n` + `See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host`);
      |                  ^
  605 |         }
  606 |     }
  607 | }
```

My `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: [process.env.API_STORAGE_DOMAIN]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can just create the `next.config.js` in the root of the Next.js app.

Comment: Hi @juliomalves! I updated my question, can you take a look?

Comment: Are you still seeing the exact same error? What value do you have for `process.env.API_STORAGE_DOMAIN`?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, .env is `.env.production` and `.env.development` and inside this files have: `API_STORAGE_DOMAIN=the-project-name-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com`

Comment: You're setting the s3 bucket domain but the error complains about `localhost` not being configured: _"hostname "localhost" is not configured under images in your next.config.js"_.

Comment: Exactly @juliomalves, where I configure that? In `.env`?

Comment: Wherever you want. You could just try hardcoding `'localhost'` in the `domains` array, in addition to what you already have, just to test it works. That array can contain several domains.

Comment: Wow it worked @juliomalves, thank you very much! wanted to rate your answer, but thanks again anyway!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! I just add "localhost" in my domains in `next.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loader function to load the image from its destination and then  call the loader function in the loader attribute of the image tag.

Here is the syntax for a loader function (taken from the [next.js loader function documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)):

```
import Image from 'next/image'

const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `https://example.com/${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`
}

const MyImage = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image
      loader={myLoader}
      src="me.png"
      alt="Picture of the author"
      width={500}
      height={500}
    />
  )
}
```

See also the solutions here, especially Taskmaster's sample loader function code:

[Got an error Invalid src prop ('here is a link') on `next/image`, hostname "localhost" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64909447/got-an-error-invalid-src-prop-here-is-a-link-on-next-image-hostname-loca)

Comment: Where I make this function?

Comment: You should be able to make the function in the same file with the image component. The loader function overrides any default loader in the image section of next.config.js, if present. See the example in the next.js image loader function documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image